# iOS, Launching Mail client in NON story mode. Howto?

Tags: android, ios, openurl

I have a button on my app that allows the User to send an email with destination address, and BODY already filled out.  I'm doing it this way....
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:];
But this method is launching the Mail app in EDIT mode. The user has the option of editing the Body and the Destination.

I am looking for a way where I can send an EMAIL with out going into edit mode. I don't want the user editing anything in the EMAIL...  I just want him to click a "SEND EMAIL" button, and the email is sent.

How is this done in iOS...
also, how would this be done in ANDROID?

Comment: I don't know about Android, but this is absolutely not possible in iOS.

Answer (score 1):

You cant do that. For such a solution, do a HTTP post to your server, and make it forward the info to a email address.

No other solution. This is for both Android and iOS.

Answer (score 0):

Only way to send an email without allowing the user to edit the contents in iOS would be to send the email via a web based script that you call remotely from the app. Doing so you wouldn't have the users email address to be the 'from' address though, so this also has its limitations.

The iOS SDK does not allow you to send emails automatically from your users account without them pressing the Send button on the compose email screen.